# How to get the URL of the shipping step in the checkout?

Tags: checkout, url

I am using magento 1.9.

As you know when you are going to pay your order you go thrue the checkout steps.

My checkout URL is looking like this: http://www.mymagento.com/checkout/onepage/ and this URL is not changing while you are going thrue all the steps.

My qeustion is:

Is it possible to get the direct link of the shipping step from the checkout for example ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To get the link or the change the link in the browser address bar? The one page checkout using ajax to change/update the content

Comment: Yes exactly. So it is impossible ?

Comment: If what is possible?

Comment: Is it possible to get the direct link to the shipping step in the checkout page ?

Comment: What issue are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am confused by your question technically you can get the direct url and visit it but since these pages are aimed to be loaded via ajax they do not contain the full page information such as header and footer so it would look a bit odd.

Technically the url would be `/checkout/onepage/shippingmethod` but as I said this would show an unstyled page with no header or footer simply your shipping methods. It would also simply show an error if there was no address attached to the quote as if this is the case the system cannot calculate the valid shipping methods for the quote.